# How to set timer job interval?

Tags: timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

**How can we set timer job so that it will run on specific date of month?**
 
For example, i want schedule timer job to run on 2nd and 28th day of month.
 
How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to configure a timer job in such a way to only fire on given dates, however, you could configure your timer job to run daily but include a date check as the first action in the job.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

if (date.Day.Equals(2) || date.Day.Equals(28))
{
    // It's either the 2nd or 28th of the month!
    // Put the rest of the code you want to run in here.
}

else
{
    // Do nothing - it's not the 2nd or 28th.
}
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc427068%28v=office.12%29.aspx) is a good walk through if you need more information on creating the timer job, taken from MSDN.

[Edit]

In reference to your comments on this answer.  See [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/a-complete-guide-to-writing-timer-jobs-in-sharepoint-2010/) from the sub heading **Scheduling a Job to Run Each Day**.

Comment: Hi scmc, your answer is very helpful and i really appreciate your help. 
If i need to configure my timer job on daily basis, should i need to set its interval to seconds(24hours)?

Comment: Does it need to run just just once on the 2nd/28th?  I.e. it does not recur throughout the whole day.

Comment: Just once on 2nd and 28th of month. i.e twice a month.

Comment: I've editted my answer to include a link on how to schedule a timer job to run once per day.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to schedule timerjob by date. You should create daily timerjob and check if today is the 2nd or 28th day.

Comment: Thanks, and it will be very helpful if you can give me an example on how to schedule timer job on daily basis through coding.

Comment: `YourTimerJob tJob = new YourTimerJob(jobName, webApplication);
  tJob.Schedule = new SPDailySchedule(){
                BeginHour = 4,
                EndHour = 5,
            };`
And in the Execute method check:
`if (DateTime.Now.Day.Equals(2) || DateTime.Now.Day.Equals(28))
                {your code here} `