# Timer Job bi weekly

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

can someone help me please to set the schedule of the timer job biweekly, present we are running our custom timer job every Sunday 2 am, I want to schedule the timer job run once in two weeks.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you cannot schedule it to run every two weeks. You do have however, (at least) two alternatives:

1. When the timer job runs check the week number of the current date and run only on even/odd weeks, skip and do nothing otherwise
2. Add two instances of the timer job with a monthly schedule, one of which would run the 1st and one the 14th of the month

Answer (score 0):

The answers to this question says to schedule the job to run daily.  And modify the job so the first thing it does is check the date and continue if it is one of the 2 days per month it is to run.

[How to set timer job interval?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/143831/how-to-set-timer-job-interval?rq=1)